# FactoryGirl and belongs_to association when testing Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  belongs_to :user

end
```

Which is tested by:

```
describe Team do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:team)
  end

  it "should belong to a user" do
    @team = Team.create!(@attr)
    @team.should belong_to(:user)
  end
end
```

And I have the following factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :team do
    name 'Dream Team'
    sport
    user
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'Test User'
    last_name 'Last Name'
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
  end
end
```

When I test the spec, I get the following failure:

> 1) Team should belong to a user
>        Failure/Error: @team = Team.create!(@attr)
>        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>          SQLite3::ConstraintException: teams.user_id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "teams" ("created_at", "name", "sport_id", "updated_at",
>   "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Why is that? In the docs it says that to set an association you can just write the Factory name, in my case is user.

Thanks

Comment: I take it you're using either `shoulda-matchers` or `remarkable`?

Comment: Straight rspec-rails 2.13.0

Comment: Unless I'm terribly mistaken, I don't think `belong_to` is one of the default matchers in RSpec 2. You need something else to be able to write that. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FactoryGirl.attributes_for` will give you a hash containing the attributes for the specified model only, not including association attributes -- in your case, `user_id`.

That will throw up errors in case `user_id` is a required field and you're trying to create an instance of `Team` by using `FactoryGirl.create(attributes_for(:team))`.

However, if you use `FactoryGirl.create(:team)` it should give you a valid instance of `Team`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `before(:each)` with FactoryGirl and Rspec, in fact a more elegant way of creating this test, according to The Rails 4 Way Chapter 21, is by using `let(:team) { FactoryGirl.create(:team }` prior to your it statements

this allows you to not use so many instance variables, if desired I can provide an example if this explanation is not sufficient